# How to remove preconfigured zones in firewalld

Tags: firewalld

I was unable to remove any preconfigured zones.

```
[root@fabian ~]# firewall-cmd --permanent --delete-zone=block
Error: BUILTIN_ZONE: block
[root@fabian ~]#
```

Is there a way I can do that? If I just remove coresponding zone files, firewalld won't start.

If this cannot be done, why on earth one can not get rid of this builtin zones?
Just looking at predefined empty firewall makes me puke:

```
[root@fabian ~]# firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

dmz
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

drop
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

external (active)
  interfaces: enp0s26u1u1
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

home
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

internal (default, active)
  interfaces: enp4s0
  sources: 
  services: ssh
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

public
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

trusted
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

work
  interfaces: 
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

[root@fabian ~]#
```

Please save me.

Answer (score 3):

Default zones are stored in this directory:

/usr/lib/firewalld/zones

The following was pulled from after googling firewall-cmd default zones:

[https://www.linode.com/docs/security/firewalls/introduction-to-firewalld-on-centos]

Configuring FirewallD

Firewalld is configured with XML files. Except for very specific configurations, you won’t have to deal with them and firewall-cmd should be used instead.

Configuration files are located in two directories:

```
/usr/lib/FirewallD holds default configurations like default zones and common services.   Avoid updating them because those files will be overwritten by each firewalld package update.

/etc/firewalld holds system configuration files. These files will overwrite a default configuration.
```

With that said...
I removed a builtin zone named internal from the /usr/lib/FirewallD/zones and reloaded firewalld, and the zone was still there when did --list-all-zones.

So I then removed the internal zone from /etc/firewalld/zones and reloaded the firewall, and the internal is now gone.

Will it come back after a package update, don't know and haven't tried yet.

Comment: The only file in /etc/firewalld/zones is public.xml. So, nothing to delete. :-( It's CentOS 7.

Comment: It will come back after an update because the package will replace all files in /usr/lib for firewalld.

Answer (score 1):

My Debian bullseye system had a file `/etc/firewalld/zones/docker.xml`, which caused my firewalld to have a zone `docker` (visible when executing `firewall-cmd --list-all-zones`).

The only way to get rid of zone `docker` was by deleting that file:

```
rm /etc/firewalld/zones/docker.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub a feature request for this is tracked as [#897](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/897). It seems that not all built-in zones can just be removed by the user, as firewalld expects their existence to use them in rare cases. Though the discussion on that issue shows that removing those cases should be possible.

(I’m fairly new & hope putting this link with that explanation is appropriate as its own answer.)